# Using sed command to replace a line matching a variable with a new value that is stored in a variable in a file that is variable

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to use the sed command to replace a pattern-matching line (lines starting with ">") with a new line that is stored in a variable and do the iteration for all the files in the folder. I want to add a part of the old name (just letters and numbers like "ngs100") in the middle of the new name. New names must start with ">hC-19/Tb-" and end with "/2022". Here is my script:

```
for file in $1/*.fa
do
    echo "Processing file: $file"
        OLD_NAME=$(grep ">" $file)
        echo "Old name is $OLD_NAME"
         NEW_NAME=$(grep ">" $file| cut -d_ -f3| cut -d- -f1 | awk '{X = ">hC-19/Tb-" $1 "/2022"} END {print X}')
        echo "New name is $NEW_NAME"
        sed -i 's, '"$OLD_NAME"','"$NEW_NAME"',' "$file"
        CHANGED_NAME=$(grep ">" $file)
        echo "Changed name is $CHANGED_NAME"
done
```

The old name and a new name are correct in the output. But the supposed "CHANGED_NAME" is the same as the old name, meaning that nothing has changed at all, meaning that `sed -i` didn't work. How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you tried `sed -i "s/${OLD_NAME}/${NEW_NAME}/" "$file"`? (In this case the curly braces can be omitted.) I think in your example code the problem is the whitespace after the first comma (it will be prepended in the front of old_name), however `sed` doesn't require single quotes, so you can use just double quotemarks, even you can omit them.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The thing is that somehow I can't use double quotes with sed in this case. Here's the error: sed: -e expression #1, char 102: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @Sgt.Pepper that's more likely about `/` versus `,` as delimiter than about the quotes - I'm guessing at least one of `OLD_NAME` and `NEW_NAME` contains the `/` character?

Comment: Oh, true. As noted above, I added "/2022" to the line, so NEW_NAME contains / character.

Answer (score 1):

You were clever enough to use `,` as the separator for the `s` command instead of the typical `/`, which is part of your `$NEWNAME`. But even if you are sure there can be no `,` inside that line, any other character like `\` or `[` could break the script.

If you want to add  `/2022` to the end of the line starting with `>`, simply do that:

```
sed -i '/>/s,$, /2022,' "$file"
```

- `/>/` before the command means "apply that command only to lines containing `>`
- the following `s` command substitutes the ending of the line (`$`) with your new ending

This way you don't risk your command getting broken by unknown file contents.

Btw, if you want to add that string to the end of the old line, why don't you simply do `NEW_NAME="$OLD_NAME /2022"` instead of `grep`ping again and piping to `awk`?

Comment: Actually, my code is a bit different. I wanted to add a part of the old name (just letters and numbers) in the middle of the new name. 
```#!/bin/bash
for file in $1/*.fa
do
   echo "Processing file: ${file}"
        OLD_NAME=$(grep ">" $file)
        echo "Old name is $OLD_NAME"
        NEW_NAME=$(grep ">" $file| cut -d_ -f3| cut -d- -f1 | awk '{X = ">hC-19/Tb-" $1 "/2022"} END {print X}')
        echo "New name is $NEW_NAME"
        sed -i 's, '"$OLD_NAME"','"$NEW_NAME"',' "$file"
        CHANGED_NAME=$(grep ">" $file)
        echo "Changed name is $CHANGED_NAME"
done```

Comment: Hard to read that way. How about editing the question to ask for what you really want?

Comment: Ok, I updated it.